# Ms Access Form - How to completely filter text using search button

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

```
`Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Dim argcount As Integer
Dim mysql As String, msg As String, mysource As String, mycriteria As String,                   mysource1 As String, mysql1 As String

 Private Sub AddtoWhere(FieldValue As Variant, FieldName As String, mycriteria As String, argcount As Integer)

'  Create criteria for WHERE clause.
If FieldValue <> "" Then
    '  Add "and" if other criterion exists.
    If argcount > 0 Then
        mycriteria = mycriteria & " and "
    End If

    '  Append criterion to existing criteria.
    '  Enclose FieldValue and asterisk in quotation marks.
    mycriteria = (mycriteria & FieldName & " Like " & Chr(34) & FieldValue & Chr(42) & Chr(34))

    '  Increase argument count.
    argcount = argcount + 1
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Search_Click()

Dim Search As String

here:
argcount = 0

'  Initialize SELECT statement.
mysql = "SELECT * FROM tbltab WHERE "
mycriteria = ""
mysql1 = "SELECT * FROM tblTemp WHERE "
     mycriteria = ""
'  Use values entered in text boxes in form header to create criteria for         WHERE clause.

AddtoWhere cboProduct, "ABC1", mycriteria, argcount
AddtoWhere cboSource, "ABC2", mycriteria, argcount
AddtoWhere cboPType, "ABC3", mycriteria, argcount

'If no criterion specifed, stop the search.
'you'll be glad you did if there are thousands of Persons maybe.
If mycriteria = "" Then
mycriteria = True

End If


'  Create SELECT statement.

mysource = mysql & mycriteria

mysource1 = mysql1 & mycriteria

Dim strval As String

   'set the recordsource of the subform to the resultset

Me!sfrmCap.Form.RecordSource = mysource

Me!sfrmCapTemp.Form.RecordSource = mysource1

Exit_cmdsearch_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_cmdsearch_Click:

DoCmd.Hourglass False

DoCmd.Echo True

MsgBox Err.Description & " Person Search Command Cancelled", vbInformation,     "Person Search Command Cancelled"

Resume Exit_cmdsearch_Click

End Sub
```

`I have a form in which there are 2 subform. I have a search button which when click search record using combo box values but in one combo box it display just related record not the complete search.

Can anyone help me in this.

Thank you.

Comment: "[...] in one combo box it display just related record not the complete search." - I do not understand what that means. I thought the combo boxes were used to provide input parameters for the search, but this sounds as though they should display the search results. Can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry if i didn't explain well, combo box are use to select value or text and then text then should be use to filter datasheet below. Combo box provide input parameter for search. As you can see in image it's not showing the complete result instead it shows related record , i want it should search complete text.

Comment: by one combo box i mean that as you can see in image i have 5 combo boxes , the rest work fine , it just the source combo box that's not working fine and i am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Ok. So your question is, why your search algorithm isn't working as expected? Well, you'll then have to show us how you perform the search.

Comment: @Leviathan, attach is the code above.

Comment: Can you please format it (by indenting it with four spaces) and move it to a more fitting locaton inside of your question?

Comment: @Leviathan, done have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AddtoWhere()` you assemble your WHERE clause, adding new conditions like this:

```
mycriteria = (mycriteria & FieldName & " Like " & Chr(34) & FieldValue & Chr(42) & Chr(34))
```

If you are unsure about what this actually does, you can put a breakpoint on the line (double clicking in the margin in front of the line) and see for yourself while executing the program.

If you do, you'll find out that a new condition like this will be added:

```
Source Like "Pre 2017 Source1*"
```

The `*` (encoded with `Chr(42)` in your code) acts as a joker matching any characters, so this condition returns everything that begins with `Pre 2017 Source1` - as you can see in the search results.

If you do not want this behaviour, just remove the star from the SQL code and only exact matches will be returned.

Btw.: You should improve that code line like this:

```
mycriteria = mycriteria & FieldName & " LIKE '" & Replace(FieldValue, "'", "''") & "'"
```

This removes the unnecessary use of `Chr()`, replaces double quotes by single quotes as SQL string delimiters as it is recommended, and enables the code to handle values that contain quotes, which would otherwise result in a runtime error.